# SharePoint Daily Summary alert in Microsoft flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, email, alert, flow

Is there any way to get SharePoint Daily Summary alert in Microsoft flow? Below image is an example of the daily summary(several items redacted because of security concerns). So far i have been able to recreate an email when changes happen but i am unable to identify exactly what changes like in SP alerts. any help would be greatly appreciated. more background: I need to only alert those people that are listed on the ticket to be notified of a change. since we do this so often we want it automated.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online list -  there is an in built notification MS Flow configured in each list or library.... in the ribbon area just next to MSflow and Powerapps.... you can try that.

Comment: while this works for notifications which i have set up currently. It does not identify exactly what has been changed. for example the alerts that are set up will show what the old sate was vs new state. the flow just states something has changed. this provides a bunch of false alerts since people click into the ticket to read and never change anything. also people sometime enter comments and sometimes dont. with our current set up from flows we just dont see what has chnaged.